# More than one reverse URL for a Model

Tags: python, django-models

I have a model which returns one absolute URL to access the model. It works fine but now I need to return more than URLs to access the model for different purposes. I am not sure if I am doing it in the correct way.
The 'author-detail' works fine but I also need to make 'author_update' and 'author_delete' work. In my opinion, I think that the model would also require to return urls for 'author_update' and 'author_delete'. I may be wrong.
Please guide me.

```
"""Model"""
class Author(models.Model):
    """Model representing an author."""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']
        permissions = (("modify_authors", "Modify Authors"),)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'


"""View"""
class AuthorListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Author
class AuthorDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Author
class AuthorCreate( LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    initial = {'date_of_death': '05/01/2018'}
    #permission_required = 'catalog.modify_authors'

class AuthorUpdate(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death']
    permission_required = 'catalog.modify_authors'

class AuthorDelete(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Author
    success_url = reverse_lazy('authors')
    permission_required = 'catalog.modify_authors'


"""urlpatterns"""

urlpatterns += [ 
    path('authors/', views.AuthorListView.as_view(), name='authors'),
    path('author/<int:pk>', views.AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'), 
    path('author/create/', views.AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author_create'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/update/', views.AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='author_update'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/delete/', views.AuthorDelete.as_view(), name='author_delete'),
]

"""html"""
<li><a href="{% url 'author_create'%}">Create author</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'author_update'%}">Update author</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'author_delete'%}">Delete author</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to add an arg to the method to accept a url name, provided their signatures are the same:

```
def get_absolute_url(self, url):
        """Returns the url to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse(url, args=[str(self.id)])
```